# Cannot add user via google API

Tags: python-3.x, google-workspace

my name is Adrian. I want to add user to the G suite via google admin SDK via python3.

here is my problem:

I have this code:

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user']

def createUserConnection():  
   creds = None
   # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
   # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
   # time.
   if os.path.exists('token.pickle'): 
       with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
           creds = pickle.load(token, encoding='Latin-1')
   # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
   if not creds or not creds.valid:
       if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
           creds.refresh(Request())
       else:
           flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
               'credentials.json', SCOPES)
           creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
       # Save the credentials for the next run
       with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
           pickle.dump(creds, token)
   createUserConnection.service = build('admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=creds)


def addUser(name,familyName,usermail):
   print('Adding user '+usermail+' to the G suite')
   #json definition
   userInfo = json.dumps({
   "name" : {
       "givenName": name, 
       "familyName": familyName
   },
   "kind": "admin#directory#user", 
   "primaryEmail": usermail,
   "password": "Welcome1234",
   "changePasswordAtNextLogin": True 
   })
   createUserConnection.service.users().insert(body=userInfo).execute()


if __name__ == '__main__':
   createUserConnection()
   addUser("bla","bla","blabla@24i.com")
```

When i run it via python3, it rerurns an error.   File "/Users/adrianbardossy/Downloads/google_accounts/python3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 856, in execute

```
   raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)

googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?alt=json returned "Invalid Input: primary_user_email">
```

I was trying to fix by passing the username blabla instead of blabla@24i.com, still the same issue. Based on the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/admin/directory_v1/python/latest/admin_directory_v1.users.html for the insert method. Can you help me resolve the issue?

Adrian

Comment: any update guys? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gsuite

Comment: Hello, can you help me please it is stucked here for 2 weeks

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by inputting a JSON object string in the `body` argument to `service.users().insert()`. It should just be a plain python dict.

Instead of

```
userInfo = json.dumps({
    "name": ...
```

use

```
userInfo = {
    "name": ...
```

I was also stuck on this for a long time since the docs imply it should be entered as a JSON object, which I interpreted to mean "JSON object encoded as a string", but i discovered it should really just be a python object/dict.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same message error `Invalid Input: primary_user_email` using the javascript library and from what I understand it means the api couldn't find the `primaryEmail` property in your body. In other words: your JSON is malformed.

Here's my take on this issue, I use the javascript terminology but it should transfer to python as well :

If you're using the `gapi.client.directory.insert` method of adding a user you need to encapsulate your body in a `resource` property, your JSON becomes

```
{
    "resource": {
       "name" : {
           "givenName": "name",
           "familyName": "familyName"
       },
       "kind": "admin#directory#user",
       "primaryEmail": "usermail",
       "password": "password",
       "changePasswordAtNextLogin": true 
   }
}
```

However, if you're using the `gapi.client.request` method of adding a user, the library will encapsulate the JSON for you, so your body should look like this :

```
{
   "name" : {
       "givenName": "name",
       "familyName": "familyName"
   },
   "kind": "admin#directory#user",
   "primaryEmail": "usermail",
   "password": "password",
   "changePasswordAtNextLogin": true 
}
```

Short answer for OP: you're using the `insert` method, try encapsulating your JSON in a `resource` property.

Hope it helps people who stumble on this error in the future

Comment: This does not appear to be applicable to the python client/library

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but if you haven’t gotten it yet, I threw a dict into the field in lieu of doing any conversion or anything to JSON:

```py
def get_user_inf(service):
    '''
    This initiates the collection of user data.
    '''

    user_fname = str(input('What is the new hires first name? : '))
    user_lname = str(input('What is the new hires last name? :  '))
    user_email = str(input('What is the new hires email? : '))

    new_user = {
        "name": {
            "givenName": user_fname,
            "fullName": user_fname + " " + user_lname,
            "familyName": user_lname,
        },
        "primaryEmail": user_fname + '.' + user_lname + "@hometownticketing.com",
        "recoveryEmail": user_email,
        "password": "Temp42!!!",
        "changePasswordAtNextLogin": True,
    }

    user = service.users().insert(body=new_user).execute()
```